# Find string with if condition using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe with 10,000 rows(and still growing) and 10 columns.

This data is for daily sales of supplier, so the same product name is repeated every day.

What I am trying to do is to find the end of each company(buyer) order process.

The data set look like this :

```
Product   Date     Tomorrow                    TodaysSummary                 Buyer 
AX1    |2/1/2019|Invoicing             |The product request started today |  HTN
X5L    |2/1/2019|Future request planing|No operation update               |  null
NO6    |2/1/2019|Request ended         |Operation product request ended   |  KLW
AX1    |3/1/2019|Logistic planning     |Product requested still pending   |  HTN
X5L    |3/1/2019|Processing order      |A new product request started     |  LKJ
NO6    |3/1/2019|No new request        |No update for new operation       |  null
AX1    |4/1/2019|Product order ended   |Closing the request               |  HTN
X5L    |4/1/2019|Planning logistic     |The product ended                 |  LKJ
NO6    |4/1/2019|New Request Planing   |No update for new operation       |  null
```

So where two rows have the same product name and the same company name; search for strings ended **and** product (in any order), in columns: Tomorrow ***or** TodaysSummary .

I tried this from this:

```
cols = ['Tomorrow', 'TodaysSummary']
df2 = df2[df2.apply(lambda x : x.str.endswith('ended')).any(axis=1)]
```

The result I get is:

```
Product   Date     Tomorrow                    TodaysSummary                 Buyer 
NO6    |2/1/2019|Request ended         |Operation product request ended   |  KLW
```

But there are 2 issues with it:

- It returns the row only if (ended) in both columns, and I need it in any of the two columns.
- It does not compare product name or company name before finding the string

  The result I should get:

```
Product   Date     Tomorrow                    TodaysSummary                Buyer 
NO6    |2/1/2019|Request ended         |Operation product request ended   |  KLW
AX1    |4/1/2019|Product order ended   |Closing the request               |  HTN
X5L    |4/1/2019|Planning logistic     |The product request ended         |  LKJ
```

Comment: `It does not compare product name or company name before finding the string` can you explain more?

Comment: It means it should make sue that is the row with same product & company. The data is entered daily for the same product and most times the the company will be shown for couple of days . ""This data is for daily sales of supplier, so the same product name is repeated every day."" + the function should look for the string (ended and product) in multiple column but it should return the row if it is found in any of the columns

Comment: OK, so is necessary sort data? Or get first `AX1`, get first `HTN` and alla nother rows if for `AX1` is no `HTN` is necessry remove? Because not understand sense of this

Comment: If (AX1(index 0) ==AX1(index 6) and HTN(index 0) ==HTN(index 6) start searching for (ended and product) in Tomorrow **OR**  TodaysSummary not **AND*, if it find it show the row if not go to the next row with same conditions. And if buyer != buyer return the last matched row and start doing the function again for the new buyer value.

Comment: is possible change data sample for not match data of `.endswith('ended')` because if compare `product name or company name` it not match? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: well the problem that my original data is similar to the example if not more complex